# How to increment a count in model and save in database using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have use a count to but it will save only 1 in database what did i do wrong

```
public function create_invoice() 
{
    $count = 1;

    $data = array(

        'invoice_no' => $count
    );

    $count++;

    return $this->db->insert('invoice', $data);
}
```

Comment: what else do you expect ?

Comment: @sintakonte He is expecting, when He call ```create_invoice()``` second time, ```$count``` must be 2. It means he wants ```invoice_no``` auto increment by 1.

Comment: @hemalherath: please set ```invoice_no``` column auto increment in database instead of incrementing like this.